# How to POST data from Puppeteer to Google Apps Script web app API endpoint in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-apps-script, puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer scraping script that successfully fetches my target data. Now, I want to post the data in my Google Apps Script web app and read it with `doPost()` in GAS. I expect to see the data in my Google Sheets file but instead I get the following error.

> TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded
>       at /Users/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:142:21
>     -- ASYNC --
>       at Frame. (/Users/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>       at Page.goto (/Users/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:675:49)
>       at Page. (/Users/path/to/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
>       at /Users/path/to/proto.js:215:37
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
>     name: 'TimeoutError'
>   }

What am I doing wrong?

puppeteer.js

```
  const pagePost = await browser.newPage();

  ...
  postUrl = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/abcdexyz123/exec' // GAS endpoint, tested and working
  itemsAsCsv = // csv data
  ...

  // Allows you to intercept a request; must appear before
  // your first page.goto()
  await pagePost.setRequestInterception(true);

  // Request intercept handler... will be triggered with 
  // each page.goto() statement
  pagePost.on('request', interceptedRequest => {

      // Here, is where you change the request method and 
      // add your post data
      var data = {
          method: POST,
          postData: itemsAsCsv,
      };

      // Request modified... finish sending! 
      interceptedRequest.continue(data);
  });

  // Navigate, trigger the intercept, and resolve the response
  try {
    const response = await pagePost.goto(postUrl);     
    const responseBody = await response.text();
    console.log(responseBody);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)   
  }

  // // Close the browser - done! 
  // await browser.close();

  // end POST

  await browser.close();
```

Comment: How long does your `doPost()` take to execute completely? See Script editor> executions. Try setting `await pagePost.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); `

Comment: @TheMaster: That didn't work. I wonder if I need to do something like set the `Content-Type` header to `CSV` or something like that? I've tried different things but nothing is working.

Comment: @TheMaster: Could it possibly be a CORS issue?

Comment: *How long does your doPost() take to execute completely? See Script editor> executions* I'm not sure if it's cors. Is the app published as anyone even anonymous can access? I believe cors is disabled by default in puppeteer. If it's  indeed cors and you've allowed anonymous access, you need to send data as plain string with type `text/plain` to avoid preflight.

Comment: @TheMaster: I have two executions (from other procedures) <1 sec. But that includes a Hello world response. I'm not sure if I have any successful executions loading data. I don't think so. How do I set content type in my code? I imagine it's when I set the `data` options but what would that line look like? And what if it's CSV? Or JSON?

Comment: If your want to avoid cors preflight, it should be `text/plain` or url form encoded or multipart/form data as ContentType(anything else except those 3 will trigger preflight). Type is usually set in headers. But I'm not familiar with puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was attempting to write an array of arrays. But I was only reading a single array (row).

The fix was to change

```
postData: itemsAsCsv,
```

to

```
postData: itemsAsCsv[0],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using given below syntax while crawling pages.

```
const response = await pagePost.goto(postUrl, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0})
```

Comment: That didn't work. I wonder if I need to do something like set the `Content-Type` header to `CSV` or something like that? I've tried different things but nothing is working.

Comment: Could it possibly be a CORS issue?

Comment: Are you successfully getting data from puppeteer?

Comment: `timeout: 0` is infinite. If something goes wrong, your script will hang forever until killed, making it [hard to debug](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts). Better to use a few-minute timeout so you can get a clear-cut error and diagnose the problem.